# I want to add label into input field as default value on joomla registration page

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to add label into input field as default value on joomla registration page `<?php echo $field->input;?>`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your

> en-GB.com_users.ini

located in

> language/en-GB

You can find more info [Here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-edit-registration-page.html)